# Employee Test Result Failure Revealed

Tags: professionalism, privacy, test, gdpr

I recently (and embarrasingly) failed an email phishing test at work when I should have known better. At the time I was distracted and not paying attention properly and it caught me out, which proves it's worth doing and I learned from it!

We're only a small company (30 people). Not may people failed. I have since learned that the person running the tests revealed that I had failed during a board meeting.

I don't find this acceptable. I think it's unprofessional and an invasion of my privacy.

I'm currently ensuring I have up to date copies of our internal policies to see where I stand.

Does anyone have any ideas/information on where I can look into how I should be protected by (say) GDPR and any other standards?

Thanks.

An edit for any future readers. Replies so far seem to think I have an issue with being tested, or the results being discussed. I don't! I'm just suprised that I got named rather than an overall score and data of an anonymised nature being used.

Comment: Protected against what? All the person running the test do is disclose your failure with the, I assume, previously agreed test. How is that invading your privacy?

Comment: I thought you were going to say they revealed it to other employees, that might be odd, but in a board meeting?? I don't see an issue there...

Comment: If it was in a board meeting, I don't see an issue with it. If they had advertised it to the entire company, I'd be a bit miffed. Regardless, there's not much you can expect from a privacy standpoint in this situation unless it's a healthcare/personal matter. Even then, HIPPA/similar doesn't apply since they're likely not a covered entity. In that case, they generally avoid talking about health matters as a matter of respect. You failing a phishing test is fair game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Let it go**

I had this happen to me when I worked at a bank. One of my co-workers thought it was fishy (and he worked for IT Security) so we poked around the email and eventually clicked on it. We both got an email berating us over it. Our boss got an email informing him of the need to discuss IT security with us.

We laughed about it and moved on. It never came up again. Nobody from IT came to throw us out of the building. Nobody in IT even bothered to mock us about failing it.

This is one of those things that comes with a gentle reminder and perhaps some light mockery and then disappears forever.

Fighting over it will only get you labeled troublesome and embarrass you far more than continuing on with your job. Failing a phishing test is not juicy gossip. "Employee fights over phishing test" will reach far more ears.

I personally would not have revealed it publicly because some people would find it rather embarrassing, but your proposed cure is more harmful to you.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for the measured response. Am suprised it happened but need to chill out :)

Comment: @Chris The fact that you're surprised may be a symptom of the [Dunning–Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect). The test is to educate people of Phishing, and you got educated. However, you are surprised by your need of education and excused it with "distractions". Just replace clicking the email with... say, depositing money to a stranger's account and see how that reads.

Comment: @Nelson I'm not surprised by being caught out by Phishing, it was a clever attack and you're right it did educate me. I was suprised at my identity being disclosed and the need to do so.

Answer (score 9):

The test was carried out to know how many (and which) employees posed a potential security risk in terms of being vulnerable to this sort of threat. What do you expect the people who are running the test to do if not to report on the results?

> I don't find this acceptable. I think it's unprofessional and an invasion of my privacy.

I can understand why you might find it embarrassing but unless they were all pointing and laughing or similar it's not unprofessional. As for your privacy why would it be? Presumably you weren't sending communications of a personal nature when you fell for the phish - you were acting in your professional capacity and the people running the test were acting in their professional capacity when they ran the test and reported on the results.

> I should be protected by (say) GDPR and any other standards?

Well, assuming you were in the EU then GDPR would cover the data of the test results - the outcome of the test has to be recorded against some PII for them to know it was you. I mean if you really dig you might be able to find some kind of loophole where they didn't have a suitable lawful basis for the processing/storing the PII for the purposes of the test but I doubt it - and even if you **do** find anything all you'll really do is suceed in escalating the situation from "OP fell for a phishing test, that was kind of embarrassing" to "OP's a nutcase", you can't un-ring this bell, they already *know* you failed the phishing test. No amount of right to erasure in the world is going to change that.

Honestly I think you just need to take this like a grown up - and be more careful with your inbox in future.

Comment: I'd add that failing those is not career-ending, not even close to it. In every company, I've seen them done someone has always failed, and not once were they met with any punishment for it as that is not the point of them. The point is to educate and expose how easy those attacks are to carry out, and usually in a way that the board will understand.

Comment: I think I expected the personal details of any tests like this to be kept private. Surely saying "n people failed" is sufficient rather than naming and shaming? But an interesting viewpoint, albeit written in a rather agressive manner.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Absolutely.. they're generally run to identify training needs, not as sticks to beat people with.

Comment: @Chris The thing is without naming the people who failed the information is of limited value - say they intend to organize training/education on the issue for those who need it. They need to know *who* those people are. As others have alluded to in comments if they were broadcasting the results then the "n-people failed" approach is perhaps more appropriate, but this wasn't that - it was a board meeting.

Comment: "What do you expect the people who are running the test to do if not to report on the results?" Standard practice is to give numbers, not names. "X amount of people did this" rather than "Claire and Bob did this". The board doesn't need to know names, they just need to know that appropriate action is being taken.

Comment: @520saysReinstateMonica For sufficient numbers of X and/or in sufficiently large sample sizes sure.. but that's about convenience and effectiveness in reporting - it's not a privacy or professionalism issue. Go into a board meeting to report on a test of 30 people and say 2 failed and the very next question that's going to be asked is "which two?"

Comment: "Two employees of X division. They have not been named in this report to prevent further embarrassment, however they have been notified and have been put on a security training program to ensure this doesn't happen again".

Comment: @520saysReinstateMonica It's a company of thirty people.. saying "two employees of X division" probably pins it down anyway. And remember - it's the *board of directors* if they want to know which of their employees failed a phishing test, they're allowed to know, this isn't an employee's deeply personal information - it's the result of a workplace evaluation.

Comment: @motosubatsu - yeah, in our company, someone needs to track if the same people are failing the tests, for additional training, at the very least.  When I failed, my boss was notified, and it was a hit in my performance review.  I'm in IT, and that was appropriate.

Comment: Saying Mr. X Or Ms. Y failed isn’t considered PII.